# Hiding all points above a plotted line in a scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Plotting 2 lists of galaxy equivalent width ratios, Im plotting them against each other then I want to eliminate all points above the line `y=(0.61)/(x-0.05)+1.3` so that only points below remain in the plot. Here is what I have so far and I've looked on stack overflow but am lost on how to make this happen. Note: I only want the points above `y` not `y2` to be eliminated, thanks!

```
plt.scatter(NT,OT,s=5, c='r', marker='o')
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y=(0.61)/(x-0.05)+1.3
y2 =((0.61)/(x-0.47)) + 1.19#
plt.plot(x, y, '-k')
plt.plot(x, y2, '--k')
plt.xlabel('log(NII/HA)', color='#1C2833')
plt.ylabel('log(OIII/HB)', color='#1C2833')
plt.ylim((-1,1.5))   
plt.xlim((-2,0.5))
```

thanks in advance any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If y2 contains your points then you could just use a list comprehension to filter out values for y2 given an x that are above y.

Comment: both y and y2 are lines plotted on the scatter plot and the data plotted it NT and OT these are the 2 ratios, im usure on how you would use a list comprehension to make this work

Comment: I see. You could go through each point you have for NT and OT and only include it in the list of points to be graphed if it is below the y-value that it must be under. Similar to the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808490/8206432). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to do this will be to simply filter the desired points out before plotting, you can do so with

```
filteredx = list()
filteredy = list()
for ii in range(len(NT)):
    if OT[ii] < (0.61) / (NT[ii] - 0.05) + 1.3:    #Adjust equation as needed
        filteredx.append(NT[ii])
        filteredy.append(OT[ii])
plt.scatter(filteredx, filteredy)
```

For a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create random data for demonstration
np.random.seed(1)
n = 200
datay = np.random.randn(n)*50
datax = np.random.randn(n)*1.5
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
y = (0.61) / (x - 0.05) + 1.3

filteredx = list()
filteredy = list()
plt.scatter(datax, datay, marker='o', color='g', label="All Points")
for ii in range(n):
    if datay[ii] < (0.61) / (datax[ii] - 0.05) + 1.3:
        filteredx.append(datax[ii])
        filteredy.append(datay[ii])
plt.scatter(filteredx, filteredy, marker='.', color='r', label="After Filtering")
plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Filtering demonstration]

To remove the asymptote you can filter for values larger than and less than
`x = 0.05` and plot the two groups separately, i.e.

```
plt.plot(x[x < 0.05], y[x < 0.05], linewidth=1, linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.plot(x[x > 0.05], y[x > 0.05], linewidth=1, linestyle='-', color='b')
```

[image: Filtering below line]

You do in this case need to specify the color, otherwise the two regions will have different colors. Additionally, if you need to label the line for the legend, simply give one of the two a `label` - if you give one to each region you will end up getting two legend entries.

Comment: Thankyou! this is exactly what I was after

Comment: Sorry I didnt include this in the first post, would you happen to know how to hide the asymptote, I've scoured the matplotlib documentation, but cant see that there is a way, thanks any help appreciated!

Comment: @JoshMarsh Do you mean just the vertical section of the blue line? Or the whole thing?

Comment: just the vertical part, i have limited the axis but I think that just puts a visual limit. As that vertical line is connecting -infinity to +infinity i need a method of removing it, thanks!

Comment: @JoshMarsh See the edited answer, and if it solves the problem make sure to hit the check mark to accept it