# Removing asymptote from scatter plot with line plotted on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Plotting 2 lists of galaxy equivalent width ratios, I am plotting them against each other. Then I want to eliminate all points above the line y=(0.61)/(x-0.05)+1.3 so that only points below the line remain in the plot. However because this plotted line creates an asymptote some points which I don't want remain visible because they are technically below the line. Here is what I have so far:

```
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
filteredx = list()
filteredy = list()
for ii in range(20000):
    if OT[ii] < (0.61) / (NT[ii] - 0.05) + 1.3:
        filteredx.append(NT[ii])
        filteredy.append(OT[ii])
plt.scatter(filteredx, filteredy, marker='.', color='r', label="StarBursts")
plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
plt.plot(x, y, '-k')
plt.plot(x, y2, '--k')
plt.xlabel('log(NII/HA)', color='#1C2833')
plt.ylabel('log(OIII/HB)', color='#1C2833')
plt.ylim(-1,1.5)   
plt.xlim(-2,0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know a method that would eliminate the asymptote and therefore cause these points to disappear?

#### Edit

Here is the plot for more clarity:

[image: plot]

Comment: You need to provide [ a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently it is hard to imagine the problem in mind without seeing the actual problematic figure you are getting

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow, ive added an image of the plot all the points on the right of the plot I am trying to hide because they would still be under the line mentioned above if the asymptote wasnt plotted (seen just to the left of x=0), I hope this makes it clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
plt.plot(x, y, '-k')
```

to

```
plt.plot(x[x > 0.05], y[x > 0.05], '-k')
plt.plot(x[x < 0.05], y[x < 0.05], '-k')
```

Using randomly generated data:

[image]

The asymptote will not be plotted. See my answer to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845109/hiding-all-points-above-a-plotted-line-in-a-scatter-plot/54849776#54849776) for a complete example with more detail.